# Make .NET Core app reload experience like angular/react

Tags: c#, .net, ajax, asp.net-core

I have a website build with .net core technology.

there are menu on left side, and display content on right side.

but currently, when I click to menu, it reload entire page and load all menu again and then load content of page.

what I want is, when click on menu, it should load content for that menu without reloading page.

below code I tried, but I think that causes issue, because I used global variable in JavaScript in  every page, so when I click on any menu that will call my below function and load content, but when I click on another menu it load another page, but first page global variable are still access on second page.

```
 async function getPage(url) {
            let response = await fetch(url);
            let data = await response.text();
            return data;
        }

        function loadPage(url) {
            $("#main-layout-container").html("<div class='div-loader'></div>");
            getPage(url).then((data) => {
                $("#main-layout-container").html(data);
            });
        }
```

Comment: Your requirement is to click on the menu bar on the left, and the corresponding content will be displayed on the right, that's all, right?

Comment: yes @Chaodeng
but my project is ongoing and there are so many pages.

Answer (score 0):

If you use JavaScript, I wrote a simple demo:

View：

```
<div class="all">
    <div class="menu">
        <ul class="first">
            <li>
                First-level directory-1
                <ul class="sec">
                    <li>1-1</li>
                </ul>
                <div class="content">1-1：content</div>
            </li>
            <li>
                First-level directory-2
                <ul class="sec">
                    <li>2-1</li>
                    <li>2-2</li>
                </ul>

                <div class="content">2-1：content</div>
                <div class="content">2-2：content
                </div>
            </li>
            <li>
                First-level directory-3
                <ul class="sec">
                    <li>3-1</li>
                    <li>3-2</li>
                    <li>3-3</li>
                </ul>
                <div class="content">3-1：content</div>
                <div class="content">3-2：content</div>
                <div class="content">3-3：content</div>
            </li>
            <li>
                First-level directory-4
                <ul class="sec">
                    <li>4-1</li>
                    <li>4-2</li>
                    <li>4-3</li>
                    <li>4-4</li>
                </ul>
                <div class="content">4-1：content</div>
                <div class="content">4-2：content</div>
                <div class="content">4-3：content</div>
                <div class="content">4-4：content</div>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>

    <div class="clear"></div>
</div>


@section Scripts{
    <script src="~/jquery/jquery.js"></script>
    <link href="~/css/test.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<script>
    var firstList = $('.first > li'); // Grab the first level menu li
    var secList = $('.sec'); // Grab the ul of the secondary menu for easy operation
    secList.hide();

    for (var i = 0; i < secList.length; i++) {
        firstList.eq(i).children('.content').hide();
    }

    firstList.eq(0).children('.content').eq(0).show(); //The content below 1.1 is displayed by default

    var ind = 0; // Define variables to store the subscript of the first-level menu when clicked

    // Click event of the first level menu
    firstList.click(function () {
        ind = $(this).index();

        if (secList.eq(ind).hasClass('show')) {
            for (var j = 0; j < secList.length; j++) {
                secList.eq(j).hide();
            }
            secList.eq(ind).removeClass('show');
        } else {
            for (var k = 0; k < secList.length; k++) {
                secList.eq(k).hide().removeClass('show');
            }
            secList.eq(ind).show();
            secList.eq(ind).addClass('show');
        }
    });

    // Click event of secondary menu
    $('.sec > li').click(function (event) {
        var sec = $(this).index();

        for (var i = 0; i < secList.length; i++) {
            firstList.eq(i).children('.content').hide();
        }
        firstList.eq(ind).children('.content').eq(sec).show();

        event.stopPropagation(); // Prevent events from bubbling up
    });
</script>
}
```

Demonstration effect:

[image]